# How to make sure a prop of a function implements an interface

Tags: typescript

I have the function

```
const myFunc = (data)=> {
  callOtherFunction( data.id )
  return { first: 1, second: 2, data }
}
```

How would I specify a type for this function and its return that anything can be passed in to this function as long as the following interface is fulfilled

```
interface Node {
 id: string;
}
```

Comment: `(data: Node)`? I'd strongly recommend reading through the basic TS docs.

Comment: And I strongly agree with @jonrsharpe. You can't short-cut learning to program by seeking quick answers here. Take some time to get acquainted with the tool.

Comment: How to specify the return value is *also* covered in the documentation. It's still unclear what specific problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Give the generic type to your function.

```
interface TNode {
 id: string;
}

const myFunc = <T extends TNode>(data: T)=> {
  return data.id
}

myFunc({id: '1', name: "Siraj"});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=11#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoDkD2ATFBvAKGWGwC5kBnMKUAcwG4CBfAghTEK5AWwE8AxAK4gEyALzIAPKmQQAHpBDYKaLLgB8ACmxwwccqgCUY9ckLJkUCGEFQQyHXoB0JZq1CRYiFAGVM3CAB5MAALaFReAAd8IgsScioaEAZY5BA4AITqOkYWAgAba2R9ZD8A4LCoCOjxM2IyZAByAEZGgBo0jIhyACIfYCg4ACse5CZGAj4hEU04Q3ogA)

---

Without generic, it may cause you a problem, as explained below.

```
interface TNode {
 id: string;
}

const myFunc = (data: TNode)=> {
  return data.id
}

myFunc({id: 'as', name: 'Siraj'});
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/*
Argument of type '{ id: string; name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TNode'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'TNode'.(2345)
*/
```

Though they can be avoided using typecasting, using generics is better than casting manually.

```
myFunc({id: 'as', name: 'Siraj'} as TNode);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoDkD2ATFBvAKGWGwC5kBnMKUAcwG4CBfAghTEK5AWwE8AxAK4gEyALzIAFNjhg45DDggBKMQD5khZMigQwgqCGQy5AOhLNWfISMl5iZZAHI4FJwBpkIONwjknAMrAUHAAVk7ITMqMBNbCCHYk-q4eXj5+zkEh4UzIrmhYuNFAA)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... I see that my question was to vague - sorry - I tried to clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: What does your second paragraph mean? TypeScript is *structurally* typed, anything with an id prop will be accepted.

Comment: Let me give you example without generic it will sure give you an error, @jonrsharpe

Comment: Only if you specifically pass an object literal, typed *only* by the function parameter type, though. That's not a common use case.

Comment: Yes, but the best solution of the problem, *How to accept any type that satisfies a particular type* is using generics, there's always another way of doing it, but I'm just telling the best way.

Comment: I would argue that in that case it's *worse*. The error tells you the right thing - you're passing a literal object some of whose props *cannot be used* by the function you're passing it to. This usually indicates a problem with your understanding, e.g. that you're passing a config option (one of the most common non-test cases for passing a literal) that doesn't exist.

Comment: *you're passing a literal object some of whose props cannot be used by the function you're passing it to.*

You're right, that anything beside id is unknown to the function, but what I have answered is *anything can be passed as long as it is satisfying {id: string} condition*.

What you tell may also do the job, but what I'm doing wrong here?
The meaning of `T extends SomeType` is exactly what OP asked, pass anything with a constraint `SomeType`.

Comment: BTW,  what we're arguing has no end, as both things are doing the job, and it is all upon the preference and opinion of the developer. :)